# How to generate dynamic textbox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new in vb.net and I have successfully generate textbox dynamically as below image [image]

but my problem is, I want my output to be like this

[image]

I have been use code below to generate those textbox. Could anybody fixed my code. Thanks

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click

    Dim table1 As Table

    table1 = GetRow(txtRow.Text)
    table1 = GetColumn(txtColumn.Text)

End Sub

Private Function GetRow(ByVal strRow As String)

    Dim txt1 As TextBox
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < "" & txtRow.Text & ""

        txt1 = New TextBox()
        txt1.ID = "myTextBox" & i
        Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1)
        Dim lit As New Literal()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lit)
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)

    End While

End Function

Private Function GetColumn(ByVal strColomn As String)

    Dim txt1 As TextBox
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < "" & txtColumn.Text & ""

        txt1 = New TextBox()
        txt1.ID = "myTextBox" & i
        Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1)
        Dim lit As New Literal()
        lit.Text = "<br>"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lit)
        System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)

    End While
   End Function
 End Class
```

Comment: use 2 For Each loops - one for row, one for col - so you know where to position each one.  and use variables of the proper type rather than textboxes.

Comment: i want to use textbox because i want to insert data inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls after by using a sub like this

```
private sub generate_table
for (i=0) to txtRow.Text do
  for (j=0) to txtColumn.Text do
      txt1 = New TextBox()
      txt1.ID = "myTextBox" & (i + j).tostring
      txt1.Location = New Point(i * tzt1.Size.Height, j * txt1.Size.Width)
      Panel1.Controls.Add(txt1)
  end for
end for
end sub
```

Comment: i got a lots of error by using this code and this is one of them, 'Location, txt1.Size.Height, txt1.Size.Width is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox'